# Trouble with google map Api, for locating adress

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, google-maps

Hi have some trouble while using javascript and google api for locating adress.

When I use that code, it works fine :

```
var options = {
        types: ['(cities)'],
        componentRestrictions: {
            country: 'fr'
        }
    };
    var input = document.getElementById('location');
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

But when I want to use multi input, for having many adresses, it does not work,

I tried to  change the getElementById to getElementsByClassName('location')

it return to me `TypeError: undefined is not a function` all elements input that need to have this autocomplete script do have a class named "location".

I do not know what I'm doing wrong. all example I have seen, show only for one input, so I don't know if this script is able to work with many inputs using classname.

Anykind of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you changed `location` from ID to class in your HTML source?

Comment: yes I did it. In fact I remove the id, and I put instead class

Comment: What browser are you using? [check compatibility](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp) with that function/

Comment: I use chrome from google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autocomplete expects as first argument a DOMNode, but  `getElementsByClassName` returns a DOMNodeList.

You must iterate over the items of this Nodelist and apply the `Autocomplete`.

**using native JS/DOM:**

```
    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('someClass');

     for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i){
        new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputs[i], options);
    }
```

**using jQuery:**

```
     $('.someClass').each(function(){
         new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this, options);
     });
```

Comment: do you have a tutorial on how to do that, because, it is the first time I'm trying to use javascript. I also tried in jquery $('.location') but I have the same result

Comment: I've tried that, but not working ` var input = $('.google');
    jQuery.each(input, function(){
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

    });`

Comment: you're good, thanks . all works fine, now I know that I can not use any class without a loop for that kind of work